# Django uwsgi + nginx repeated processes

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, uwsgi, wsgi

I have my application deployed in django web framework running with wsgi + nginx on the production env. Recently, i found some weird behavior from wsgi where it starts executing/repeating the function if the original request does not complete within 4-5 minutes. I increased the read_timeout and write_timeout under nginx config file, however, this issue is still there!! any expert on nginx uwsgi deployment? snippet from nginx.conf file:-

```
location /netadc/ {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include    /apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi_params;# the uwsgi_params file you installed
            uwsgi_read_timeout 1800;
            uwsgi_send_timeout 1800;
            proxy_read_timeout 1800;


    }
```

Basically this feature/script does lot of pre-validations, creates a snapshot of the n/w devices, pushes configs to around 30-40 devices and does post validations. so it takes 2-3 mins minimum to execute. sometimes when it takes more than 5 mins., it restarts the wsgi process, but not sure why... since i already increased the timeout to 30 mins as shown above.

uwsgi_params :-

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

There is no error in nginx error file or access log file that I can locate.

nginx.conf file:-

```
 upstream django {
        server unix:///apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi/tmp/netadc.sock; # for a file socket
        #server 127.0.0.1:8000; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
    }

 server {
        #listen       443;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  x.x.x.x;
        uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;

        #client timeouts
        #client_body_timeout 600;
        #client_header_timeout 600;
        #keepalive_timeout 240;
        #send_timeout 600;

        #client buffer sizes
        #client_body_buffer_size 1m;
        #client_max_body_size 32m;

        client_body_temp_path       /apps/netadc/opt/nginx/root/var/log/nginx/client_body_temp;

        ssl_certificate      cert_path;
        ssl_certificate_key  key_path;

        location /netadc/static {
                alias /apps/netadc/static;
        }

        location /netadc/ {
                uwsgi_pass  django;
                include    /apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi_params;# the uwsgi_params file you installed
                uwsgi_read_timeout 7200;
                uwsgi_send_timeout 7200;
                proxy_read_timeout 3600;

                #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  x.x.x.x;
        uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;

        location /netadc/ {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }
```

The uwsgi configuration file is the netadc_uwsgi.ini file i presume :-

```
# netadc_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

#uid    =       nginx
#gid    =       nginx

# Django-related settings
env     =       HTTPS=on

# the base directory (full path)
chdir   =       /apps/netadc

# Django's wsgi file
module  =       netadc.wsgi

# the virtualenv (full path)
home    =       home_path

# process-related settings
# master
master   =      true

# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10

buffer-size =   65536
buffer-size =   32768

# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket  = /apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi/tmp/netadc.sock

# read post data by default
post-buffering  =   1

# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
#chmod-socket    = 666

# daemonize
daemonize       =       true

# logging
logger  =       file:/apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi/tmp/netadc_uwsgi.log

# clear environment on exit
vacuum  =       true
```

Command-line arguments:-

```
/apps/netadc/.venvs/netadc/bin/uwsgi --ini /apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi/netadc_uwsgi.ini --enable-threads
```

Also another weird thing is find is some of the permissions changes after a week and some of my apps do not load.

```
[root@xxxxxxx ~]# ls -l /opt/rh/nginx16/root/var/lib/nginx/tmp/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  2 my_username nginx 4096 Aug 20 10:27 client_body
drwxrwxr-x  2 my_username nginx 4096 Jan 21  2015 fastcgi
drwxrwxr-x  2 my_username nginx 4096 Jan 21  2015 proxy
drwxrwxr-x  2 my_username nginx 4096 Jan 21  2015 scgi
drwxrwxr-x 12 my_username nginx 4096 Sep  7 12:31 uwsgi
```

Until I change the above permissions to 777, the page takes forever to load. And then after a week, it randomly changes the permisions to the above 775. It's very bizarre. No infrastructure team is doing any changes, so I am sure something in nginx+uwsgi is messing this up.

Comment: It would be nice you provide Nginx access and error logs of requests. And content of `/apps/netadc/netadc/uwsgi_params` so.

Comment: uploaded nginx.conf and uwsgi_params. Could not locate much on nginx_error.log and nginx_access.log files.

Comment: can you add your uwsgi config file or the command line arguments you use with it? uwsgi_param is not the way you configure uwsgi server operation, its just some request data from the web server that you are making available to your WSGI application request handlers

Comment: added the uwsgi.ini which contains all parameters for uwsgi and the command-line args. also posted a similar issue on my question above..